# IsTriggerEnter does not seem to be working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a 2D gameworld, I have a player square with a `Rigidbody 2D`, `Box Collider 2D`, a bigger `Box Collider 2D` as a trigger (which means the `IsTrigger` box is checked!), and a script handling `OnTriggerEnter`. And an enermy square with a `Rigidbody 2D` and `Box Collider 2D`.

But when I move my player to the enermy, my `OnTriggerEnter` was never triggered (which means no debug log is shown). And I know the colliders worked because I can push the enemy around.

Where did I set it wrong?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
}
```

**Screenshots (I don't know if this is this is what `Kashif Siddiqui` wanted!?):**
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: More details needed: 1) Did you check `isTrigger` on the box collider component? 2) Are you getting ANY debug logs whatsoever? 3) Also can you check the collision matrix and make sure the two colliders on player don't collide with each other. 4) Lastly a screenshot of the gameobjects with colliders would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using 2D Physics component, you must call the appropriate 2D Physics callbacks :

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D( Collider2D other )
{
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
}
```